# What do you call a spoken disclaimer on a radio/TV commercial?

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, legalese

The other day I was listening to the radio, and a very lengthy disclosure came on after a commercial.

I know that in printed legal documents, and even on websites, the colloquialism for legal disclosures is "fine print." On TV they will often have some disclosures in "fine print" at the bottom of the screen, but just like radio, the spokesperson usually rattles off a bunch of things towards the end.

So, is there a colloquialism for the disclosures over the radio or TV commercials?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a term in Wikipedia's article on fine print (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_print), which leads me to believe there isn't a generic term.

Comment: I've heard it referred to as "legal babble," but I can't find any sources.

Comment: *Fine print* still sounds good to me. It's just auditory "print". Also, *legalese*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about a **disclaimer**.  From Wikipedia--

> A disclaimer is generally any statement intended to specify or delimit the scope of rights and obligations that may be exercised and enforced by parties in a legally recognized relationship. In contrast to other terms for legally operative language, the term disclaimer usually implies situations that involve some level of uncertainty, waiver, or risk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Steven! Disclaimer is the "technical" term for what I am looking for, which I was interested in, but what I am more interested in is the _slang_ term for disclaimers in media (i.e. radio or TV). If you know the slang/jargony (but widely accepted) term for the fast-talking disclaimers I would love to hear it. Thank you again!

Comment: I still think that the word is disclaimer.  Unless someone in the radio business knows something that I don't (which is entirely possible), that's the term that's generally used.

Comment: @StevenLittman Definitely true ... but that's still a hypernym of radio, print and television. I think the bottom line is that there isn't a specific colloquialism like "fine print" that applies strictly to radio.

Answer (score 1):

"Spoken disclaimer" or "oral disclaimer" would differentiate radio disclaimers from written disclaimers. You could replace "disclaimer" with similar words, i.e., "spoken disclosures," "spoken fine print," or "spoken boilerplate" if those terms are more appropriate. (Maybe also "exclusions" or "representations?") But I don't know of any term for this that is specific to radio, as someone else mentioned earlier.